# Waapi easing useing custom timeline in chrome is bugged

Tags: javascript, animation, web-animations, web-animations-api

## Introduction

TLDR: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-jennings-6budz. Why does red not do the same as blue **in chrome**? Is this a bug?

Im **useing chrome** version: 76.0.3809.132. In firefox everything works as expected.

## Question

Im using the waapi to implement an animation relying on a custom timeline (for example the scroll position as timeline). The concept goes as follows:

The waapi allowes you to start an animation midway through by setting the `iterationStart` option somewhere between 0 and 1 (assuming the animation has just one iteration). When the animation is then immediately paused we get the requested frame. As the next imput gets in, we override the last frame.

So when we get the input of say 0.5 we'd use the following code:

```
//           test keyframes
elem.animate({marginLeft: ["0px", "600px"]}, {
  duration: 100, 
  easing: "linear",
  fill: "both", 
  iterations: 1, 
  iterationStart: 0.5 // input
}).pause()
```

This works perfectly, even with as we set such a frame every 1/60 sec. The problem however arises as we want to ease the aniamtion (e.g. `easing: "ease"` not `linear`). This introduces wierd gliches where the animation jumps around at **the same progress every time** (progress = iterationSatrt / input). The first jump for example is at `0.148` using `ease` as easing function. Can someone explain this behaviour? Is this a bug?

I have come across the follwing correlation. `0.148 * 2` eased with the `ease` function is just over `0.5`. To calculate this I use the `bezier-easing` library. Here the example: https://runkit.com/embed/1wetjf7jjb2s. I dont know if this is at all relevant but I thought Id share my findings.

Here the codesandbox link showing the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-jennings-6budz. Please note to not let it run too long at a time without reloading.

The blue div uses a fix to show the expected result. For this I kept `easeing: "linear"` but customly eased each input with the `bezier-easing` library as shown above (and in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, but has been fixed apparently